# Cucumber-jvm scenario is passed even one of the step fails in it. What can be the reason?

Tags: bdd, cucumber-jvm

I am using Cucumber-jvm with Serenity. In one of the scenario, i have a failed step but while executing scenario is shown as passed and step gives the error in log but overall result is passed.

Below is my pom.xml. Is it related to some Serenity Core and Serenity Cucumber version?

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <serenity.version>1.0.24</serenity.version>
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.0.4</serenity.cucumber.version>
        <webdriver.driver>firefox</webdriver.driver>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Can you add your cucumber-jvm entry/junit class?

Comment: I have figured out the issue. The issue is related to serenity-core and serenity-cucumber version. It's working when I bumped up versions to `1.0.36` and `1.0.12` respectively